# how to keep the image tag and label tag that appearing dynamically at center when flex grows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As show in below sample prototype ,I am trying to create a side navigation bar that shows images initially and when hover on the side navigation bar, the Navigation bar expands and a labels that shows description of image appears. It works well for me. I achieved this side navigation bar expansion and reduction using the concept of flex-grow property (you can check it in my code snippet to understand better what i am saying...). but my problem is that when hover the side navigation bar , the image tag moves right side to give space for label tag that appearing dynamically(when hovering side bar).
so how can I keep image at center while label tag appearing in side navigation bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    
    <style>
        *{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;box-sizing: border-box;}
        body{position:relative;height: 100vh;width: 100vw;}
        .container{position: relative;height:100%;width: 100%;display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
        .topcontainer{position: relative;width:100%;height: 75px;background-color: aqua;}
        .bottomcontainer{position: relative;width: 100%;height: 30px;border:1px solid salmon;}
        .middlecontainer{position: relative;width: 100%;height: auto;flex-grow: 1;border: 1px solid black;display: flex;}
        .rightsidenavbar{position: relative;width:auto;min-width: 75px;height:99%;border: 1px solid blue;display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content:flex-start;align-items: center;gap:10px;}
        .servicescontaienrtab{position: relative;min-width: 75px;height: auto;display: flex;justify-content:center;align-items: center;min-height: 40px;}
        .servicetabinnerCont{position:relative;width: auto;height: auto;display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: center;}
        img{height:35px; width: 35px;}
        .lableCls{display: none;}
        .mainservicecontainer{position:relative;height:99%;flex-grow: 1;width:80%;border:1px solid yellow;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topcontainer">
        </div>
        <div class="middlecontainer">
            <div class="rightsidenavbar" onmouseover="displayLabel()"  onmouseout="hideLabel()">
                <div class="servicescontaienrtab">
                    <div class="servicetabinnerCont">
                        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/7910/7910833.png" alt="imagesrc not loaded">
                        <label for="" class="lableCls">Free Service</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="servicescontaienrtab">
                    <div class="servicetabinnerCont">
                        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/7910/7910868.png" alt="imagesrc not loaded">
                        <label for="" class="lableCls">Shopping girl</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainservicecontainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomcontainer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

        const labelElement= document.querySelectorAll(".lableCls");
        function displayLabel(){
          
            for(i=0; i<labelElement.length;i++){
                labelElement[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        function hideLabel(){
            for(i=0;i<labelElement.length;i++){
                labelElement[i].style.display="none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to show/hide something on hover.
I just removed JS hover functional and use CSS instead.

Then I don't use CSS flex to center icon because you want to keep it center and stay in the same place (+with text expand to the right) when hover. So, I use calculated position (`calc()`) of margin instead.

Here is the code.

```js
// I just unfunction them you may remove it later because these are no need.

const labelElement = document.querySelectorAll(".lableCls");

function displayLabel() {

    for (i = 0; i < labelElement.length; i++) {
        //labelElement[i].style.display = "block";// no need, can be removed
    }
}

function hideLabel() {
    for (i = 0; i < labelElement.length; i++) {
        //labelElement[i].style.display = "none";// no need, can be removed
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.topcontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.bottomcontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}

.middlecontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

.rightsidenavbar {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 75px;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
.rightsidenavbar:hover .lableCls {
    display: block;
}
.rightsidenavbar:hover .servicetabinnerCont {
    margin-right: calc((75px / 2) - (35px / 2));/* 75 is column width; 35 is icon width. (add this to beautify left and right spacing.) */
}

.servicescontaienrtab {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 75px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.servicetabinnerCont {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: calc((75px / 2) - (35px / 2));/* 75 is column width; 35 is icon width. */
}

img {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}

.lableCls {
    display: none;
    word-wrap: nowrap;
}

.mainservicecontainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 99%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="topcontainer">
    </div>
    <div class="middlecontainer">
        <div class="rightsidenavbar">
            <div class="servicescontaienrtab">
                <div class="servicetabinnerCont">
                    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/7910/7910833.png" alt="imagesrc not loaded">
                    <label for="" class="lableCls">Free Service</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="servicescontaienrtab">
                <div class="servicetabinnerCont">
                    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/7910/7910868.png" alt="imagesrc not loaded">
                    <label for="" class="lableCls">Shopping girl</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainservicecontainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomcontainer">
    </div>
</div>
```